# Getting rid of "none" in result of hexdump call

Tags: python, hexdump

When using the [hexdump module](https://pypi.org/project/hexdump/),

```
from hexdump import hexdump

print(hexdump(b'\x61\x62\x63'))
```

I get the following result:

```
00000000: 61 62 63                                          abc
None
```

However, I want to get rid of the second line containing the "None". I don't understand how to do this, and the documentation is rather limited.

Comment: It looks like the `hexdump` command already outputs the result, which means it must be returning `None` and that's what you're printing with `print()`. Maybe try getting rid of your `print` statement?

Comment: You are correct, sorry and thanks.